# How do I determine which $V$ to exclude to obtain a Diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, diffeomorphism

In order to use the Lebesgue Transformation Formula, I need to find a $V$ to exclude, but I am unsure of how exactly to do it.

Example:

Spherical Coordinates

$\Phi: \mathbb R_{>0 }\times]0,\pi[\times]0,2\pi[\to\mathbb R^{3}-V$

I have been told $V:=\mathbb R_{\geq 0}\times \{0\}\times \mathbb R$

which seems intuitive

But then I get to a point of confusion when:

Cylindrical coordinates:

$\Phi: \mathbb R_{>0 }\times]0,2\pi[\times \mathbb R\to\mathbb R^{3}-V$

**BUT**

$V:=\{0\}\times\mathbb R_{\geq 0}\times \mathbb R$

Why has the excluded $V$ changed from the $y-$ to the $x-$axis?